# How to how increase/decrease compared to adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in Excel, which could have the following values

```
         A           B            C            
1     20180101    20180201     20180301
2        1           2            1
3        1           1            1
4        1           2            3
```

I want to make it visually clear in the table (I know I can use a chart) if value shows and increase or decrease compared to the previous month

This means, for example, I'd have the following logic

```
if B2 > B1 
    Make B2 Green

if B2 = B1 
    Make B2 Orange

if B2 < B1 
    Make B2 Red
```

Now, repeate for all the cells (This does mean that the values in Col A won't have any colour (which is fine))

I was unable to get this to work (using an IF formula), so I moved to Conditional Formatting which works but, every time I add a new column, I'm having to enter all the formula again to compare against the previous month. I have a very long list of formula and it's not managable.

This mock up demonstrates the final value I'm attempting to achieve

[image]

Despite searching online, I find nothing on how to do this (and have struggled to find the right words to search for). Is this achievable ?

**Edit**

Turns out my conditional formatting isn't working. This is what I've done

[image]

Comment: Conditional formatting is definitely the right way. After adding a new column, instead of adding a new conditional formatting rule try to change the range of the previous rule to include new range too.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, I've shared my conditional formatting rules, but these are not working

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Hello! I just fixed your date problem and wanted to post it, then you deleted your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were just there!

You can try and remove the quotes, and it should work.

```
Formula: =C2-B2>0
```

[image]

Edit: Also, you might consider to start applying conditional formatting from column C onwards, because column B is the first one and has nothing on the left to compare to.

Kind regards.

Comment: With this, it only applies the formatting to column B and C :(

Comment: I you take a look to column E, you will see that E column is also formatted as per "Applies to" range.

Comment: Additional check: Excel 2013: when you add a new column next to last column, conditional formatting applies automatically.

Comment: I think the issue I had was I had selected the entire table and tried to applies this. Instead, I select any single cell, added the logic and applied to the table's range! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*To get rid from the **New Column add issue related to  conditional formatting**, you need to create Dynamic Named Range.*

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$1:$Q$"&COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))
```

It will refer to all data in `A:Q`, I'm assuming there are no blanks in column A. Now you can use the `Named Data Range` to refer to all your data for conditional formatting, even if you add or delete rows/columns.

- *Adjust cell references in the formula as 
  needed.*

[image]

Comment: Where do I add this formula?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions, Click `Formula Tab` then find `Defined Names`, then you find `Define Name` click it you find `New Name` dialog box, Top is `Name` put name of your choice, and in bottom is `Refere to` write the formula in the text box.